Failed unresolved reference code after changing Android package name of source code on my forked repo
My problem is after I changed android package name from is.xyz.mpv into is.vvceasy.mpv.
I replaced xyz word with vvceasy for all source code files on my forked repository.
I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and 24.04 LTS CLI Server to build custom Android build with custom package name.
I wanted to make custom Android build than original I'd like do.
My forked repository is on GitHub: https://github.com/MartinEesmaa/mpv-android-vvc
Original: https://github.com/mpv-android/mpv-android
Everything went fine until it hit failed on Gradle build without Android Studio:
> Task :app:compileDefaultDebugKotlin FAILED
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:148:27 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:149:21 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:178:33 Unresolved reference: hasPermission
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:187:24 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate

> Task :app:compileApi29DebugKotlin
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:148:27 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:149:21 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:178:33 Unresolved reference: hasPermission
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:187:24 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate

> Task :app:compileApi29DebugKotlin FAILED

> Task :app:compileDefaultReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:148:27 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:149:21 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:178:33 Unresolved reference: hasPermission
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:187:24 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate

> Task :app:compileApi29ReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:148:27 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:149:21 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:178:33 Unresolved reference: hasPermission
e: file:///home/martineesmaa/mpv-android-vvc/app/src/main/java/is/vvceasy/mpv/FilePickerActivity.kt:187:24 Unresolved reference: filterPredicate

So I have no idea how to fix it, I tried with reset and replace words again did not work same.
Any ideas to fix for it for solution, please? Thanks! :)

MartinHero13

I tried with vanilla original repo and worked, but my forked repo did not work after Android package name change. Tried with fresh install for forked repo also did not work. Reboot did not work. Tried with Gradle 8.7 latest and 8.6 did not work.
